# How do I import my Blender 2.8 models into Blender 2.9

Tags: export

I am about to download Blender 2.9 but I don't actually know how to import my past models into Blender 2.9.

Comment: You shouldn't need to "import" them, you can just open the same as you would with 2.8.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much.

Comment: Keep it mind though that saving the project in the newer version may not allow you to open it in the older version afterwards. Better keep a copy of the old project around in case you need to go back to the older version, for whatever reason.